# Is there a way to get the icon used by a given window?

Tags: windows, icons, taskbar

All, 
  I'm working on a proof of concept replacement for the windows taskbar.  (Mostly for my own amusement than anything else)  However, one thing I was not able to find was a means of getting the icon a given window is using.  I'd be especially interested in a way to do this using a built-in dll, though at this point I'm looking for anything pointing in the right direction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[WM_GETICON](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632625.aspx) ?

Comment: Looks like what I want.  I'll mess with it tonight.  Thanks.

Comment: When I use this on windows 7, I don't get an error condition, but I always receive 0 as the Handle.